# How to check if on input matches a string pattern with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

My goal is to check if an email input field (as a user is typing characters into it), matches a pattern or not. This is my working example so far, but I feel stuck when it gets to the point of actually matching the process "while" typing...

Below is my working example which I'm trying to capitalize on...

```js
   //...

    var $attemail = mtarget.find(".my-email-field"); //INPUT

    function validateEmail(email) {
      var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
      if (re.test(email) == false) {
        console.log('Email field is not valid');
        //issueFlag.push(noticeEmail);
      }
    }

    function checkEmailOnType() {
      $attemail.on("input", function(){
        var $characters = jQuer(this).val();

        if ($characters.toLowerCase())  {
            //IF MY CHARACTER TYPING IS PASSING OR NOT PASSING 
            //MY validateEmail() FUNCTION ABOVE, HOW DO WE SAY THAT?  
        }
      });
    }

    //...
```

Comment: Use `return re.test(email)` in  `validateEmail()` and add it to your `if ($characters.toLowerCase())  {`. Yet I suggest to use it on blur or submit and not on input. I can be annoying to be pointed out the obivous before one is even finished typing.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying but how does that solve my problem in checkEmailOnType()? How do we check character typing against a function? ok,, if its just as easy as simply adding it inside the if, I'll feel like an idiot.

Comment: **How do we check character typing against a function?** by [returning a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) in that function. Yours as it is returns `undefined` which you can just change to return the result of `re.test(email)`.

Comment: As it is right now the *function* `function checkEmailOnType() {` does not really serve any puropose. You can assign the handler well without it.

Comment: JavaScript, you are right.  Thanks.

Comment: (Slightly) off topic: while your question is really about checking input pattern, you have specifically mentioned **email validation**.   Please see this question and answer: [How can I validate an email address with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) which includes a 6300 character regex (which is also not 100%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) to your function. Yours as it is returns `undefined` which you can just change to return the result of `re.test(email)`.

```
//...

var $attemail = mtarget.find(".my-email-field"); //INPUT

function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return re.test(email)
}

//function checkEmailOnType() {
  $attemail.on("input", function(){
    var $characters = jQuer(this).val();

    if ($characters.toLowerCase())  {
        //IF MY CHARACTER TYPING IS PASSING OR NOT PASSING 
        //MY validateEmail() FUNCTION ABOVE, HOW DO WE SAY THAT?
        if(validateEmail($characters) == false){
            console.log('Email field is not valid')
        }
    }
  });
//}

//...
```